# CapistranoでRailsアプリをEC2にデプロイするとエラーが発生します。「PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"」

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, postgresql, capistrano, amazon-ec2

※AWSの初心者です。今まではHerokuしか使ったことはありません。

**AWSの構成**
EC2インスタンス1個
RDSでPostgreSQL、1個

RailsアプリをCapistranoでEC2にデプロイしたいのですが、
Capistranoの下記コマンド(デプロイ)を実行すると、エラーが発生します。
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:~/sample_app$bundle exec cap production deploy

**エラー文**
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

EC2にSSHでログイン後、
sudo service postgresql start
sudo su - postgres
psql
postgres=#
postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 ec2-user  | Create role, Create DB                         | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 root      | Create role, Create DB                         | {}

postgres=# who am i
postgres-# \q
-bash-4.2$
は、実行できます。

**EC2のデータベース**
postgres=# \l
                                        List of databases
          Name          |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres               | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 sample_app_development | root     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 sample_app_test        | root     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0              | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                        |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1              | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                        |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres

**ローカル(vagrant)のデータベース**
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:~/hoge_app/config$ rails db
psql (9.5.3)
Type "help" for help.

hoge_app_development=# \l
                                        List of databases
          Name          |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 fuga_development    | vagrant  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 fuga_test           | vagrant  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres               | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 hoge_app_development | vagrant  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 hoge_app_test        | vagrant  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0              | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                        |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1              | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                        |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(7 rows)

**教えて頂きたいこと**
1. RDSでPostgreSQLを作成するとデータベースが作成されて、EC2にログイン後、「sudo service postgresql start」コマンドなどが実行できるという認識ですが、RDSでPostgreSQLを作成した場合でも、EC2にログイン後、「sudo yum install -y postgresql」などで、PostgreSQLをEC2にインストールする必要はあるのでしょうか？
2. config/database.ymlの設定は適切でしょうか？

**database.yml**
production:
 <<: *default
 adapter: postgresql
 host: 32.873.61.427
 encoding: utf8
 database: RDS作成時のインスタンス識別子
 username: ec2-user
 password: RDS作成時に設定したパスワード
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

3. エラーの発生原因

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

1. 認識が全く間違っています。RDSを作成したのならばEC2にはPostgreSQLをインストールすつ必要はありませんし、service startなんてする必要ありません。RDSというのはリレーショナルデータベース専用のサーバというイメージです。RDSのインスタンスを作成し、それが稼働してるのならばあなたはもうPostgreSQLを利用する環境を手にしています。
2. おそらく大分間違っています。`host`は`mydb.123456789012.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com`のようなRDSインスタンスのエンドポイントになるはずです。`database`はPostgreSQL内のアプリが使用するデータベース名を指定するのではないでしょうか。そして`username`にはそのデータベースにアクセス可能なPostgreSQLのユーザーを指定するのではないでしょうか。ec2-userというのはEC2インスタンスのデフォルトのユーザーのように見えます。
3. 直接的な原因は、接続しようとして`base`というユーザーの認証に失敗したことです。Peer認証となってますから、やはりRDSではなくローカルの(EC2にインストールされた)PostgreSQLに接続を試みています。

Comment: 私は質問者様が「RDS」というAWSのサービスを利用していると想定しましたが、
本当にそれは必要で、利用していますか？開発用やちょっとした検証用ならばEC2インスタンスにPostgreSQLをインストールする構成の方が費用的にもいいかもしれません。

Comment: 分かりやすく説明して頂きありがとうございます。AWS初心者でして、EC2にデプロイできずに今かなり詰まっています。追加で質問させて頂きたいのですが、RDSでPostgreSQLを作成した場合でも、database.ymlは設定する必要はあるのでしょうか？また、AWSのRDSでセキュリティグループ、パラメータグループなどがありますが、こちらの設定で注意する点などはありますでしょうか？

Comment: データベースに接続したいならばRDSであれなんであれdatabase.ymlは正しく設定してください。
AWSの設定については実際にやってみて意図した動作にならなかった場合にまた別の質問をされた方がよいでしょう。
ただし、あなたはもう少し基本的なことを学習された方がよいと思います。そうでなければとんちんかんな質問になってしまうでしょう。

Comment: アドバイス頂きありがとうございます。database.ymlの設定は修正します。AWSについては仰る通りです。書籍などでも勉強しているのですが、まだきちんと理解できていません。RDSの設定については再度調べてみます。